# Why are my calaloo leaves turning red, and are they still safe?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting, leaf-vegetables

I am growing my own [Calaloo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callaloo) in Canada from seeds obtained in Jamaica.  As the plant matures the leaves are starting to turn red.  Has anyone heard of this and are they OK to eat after they turn red?

Comment: There are at least seven plants which could be part of a calaloo recipe. What plants are you using?  Can you provide a picture?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callaloo#Plant_sources_for_callaloo_leaves

Answer (score 2):

The leaves turning red in fall is simply the [chlorophyll decaying](http://www.sciencemadesimple.com/leaves.html), and in some cases sugars build up and can make a red color. You lose some nutrition, but it shouldn't become unsafe.